# How to show a popup using an ajax-call, a controller and a fragement

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I want to implement a popup showing up on everypage under certain conditions and I want to use a controller/jsp-fragment via an ajax(). But I can't make it work. The purpose of the popup is justto display a message, no user input etc.

My controller:

```
@Controller  
public class PopupController extends AbstractController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Popup")
    public String myPopup() {

        //do stuff, add attributes etc.

        return '/mypoppath/mypopup';
    }
}
```

The Controller is new class created for this popup. Maybe I already made a mistake here? Do I have to specify the requestmethod or production type?

The ajax call

```
  popup : function() {
    console.log("before ajax");
    $.ajax({
         url: 'https//:myShop/Popup',     
          success: function(){
              Ready.displayModalPopup(Result,'modal');
              console.log("success");             
          },
          error:function(){
              console.log("ajaxerror");
          }
        });
}
```

Ready.displayModalPopup(Result,'modal'); is a function used in the project to show modal-windows and should work fine, the rest ist written by me.
the popup-function is in Ready.js and is called in initialize()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Ready.initialize();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

});
```

The fragment itself has the follwing structure

```
{
    "success" : ${success}
    ,
    <c:if test="${not empty errorMsg}">
    "message" : "<spring:theme code="${errorMsg}" />"
    ,
    </c:if>

    "myPopup": "<spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">
                            <c:url value="/Popup" var="popupUrl"/>                          

                                    <div id ="myPopup">
                       ---  header---
                       ---  body ---
                       ---  footer---
```

I used an already working jsp from an already working popup as a blueprint, so I don't think the error lies here.

Right now the behavior is the following:
If load the homepage, no popup shows up, but I can see 2(?) xhrs in the firefoxdebugger, both called "popup" one status :302 and one status 404, so I guess there is already an error within the URL, but I already tried diffrent approaches without succes (If I remember right I had a 200 once, but still no popup). Also the ajaxcall seems to throw an error all the time.

I know there are some similar topics and I tried to solve it with them, but
to be honest I am not a frontendprogrammer and also still learning backend and I coming close to despair with this topic.
It's probably some basicmistakes I do, but I can't find them.

EDIT: When I debug the controller gets called, so I think the URL is working, but there is still an error at the ajax ant the redirect to 404.

Meanwhile I added @ResponseBody. This led to to a popup, but showing only the path of the JSP, not the content.